# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

I have two lists that I'm merging into a dictionary

```
keys = ['p2p', 'groupchat']
tests_available = ['p2p_1', 'p2p_2', 'p2p_3', 'groupchat_1', 'groupchat_2']
```

The expected output will be something like

```
{'p2p': ['p2p_1', 'p2p_2', 'p2p_3'], 'groupchat': ['groupchat_1', 'groupchat_2']
}
```

My code to create the dictionary is below.

```
out = {}
out = dict.fromkeys(keys)

for tests in tests_available:
    if tests.split('_')[0] in keys:
        key = tests.split('_')[0]
        out[key].append(tests)
```

However, it is throwing the error  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' when it is trying to append the values to the key. Can anyone help me identify what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Your dict is initially empty with respect to it's items, you're trying to compile a dict with lists as the value but there is no list for that key hence the error so you can either use a default dict where the default values are empty lists or check whether the key exists or not and create a list if the key doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a defaultdict then the append call will work as the value type defaults to a list:

```
In [269]:
from collections import defaultdict
keys = ['p2p', 'groupchat']
tests_available = ['p2p_1', 'p2p_2', 'p2p_3', 'groupchat_1', 'groupchat_2']
d = defaultdict(list)
for test in tests_available:
    k = test.split('_')[0]
    if k in keys:
        d[k].append(test)
d.items()

Out[269]:
dict_items([('p2p', ['p2p_1', 'p2p_2', 'p2p_3']), ('groupchat', ['groupchat_1', 'groupchat_2'])])
```

See the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Comment: That would potentially add  new key/value pairs that are not wanted.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ah yes, it;s not testing for membership in `keys`, will update thanks

Comment: I was going to suggest the same but didn't as the OP seems to be checking for specific keys although that may be just how the happened to approach the problem. + 1 anyway, it may actually be what they want.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes the context and OP understanding of the problem domain isn't specified

Comment: This is the output that I was expecting. Thank you very much. @EdChum

Answer (score 3):

Your values are set to *None* in *fromkeys* unless you explicitly set a value:

**fromkeys(seq[, value])**

*Create a new dictionary with keys from seq and values set to value.
fromkeys() is a class method that returns a new dictionary. value defaults to None.*

In your case you need to create lists as values for each key:

```
d = {k:[] for k in keys}
```

You can also do your if check using the dict:

```
d = {k:[] for k in keys}

for test in tests_available:
    k = tests.split('_', 1)[0]
    if k in d:
        d[k].append(test)
```

You can pass a value to use to *fromkeys* but it has to be *immutable* or you will be sharing the same object among all keys.

Answer (score 1):

For a small number of keys/tests a dictionary comprehension would work as well:

```
keys = ['p2p', 'groupchat']
tests_available = ['p2p_1', 'p2p_2', 'p2p_3', 'groupchat_1', 'groupchat_2']
out = {k: [v for v in tests_available if v.startswith(k)] for k in keys}
```

Demo:

```
>>> out
{'groupchat': ['groupchat_1', 'groupchat_2'], 'p2p': ['p2p_1', 'p2p_2', 'p2p_3']}
```